# NECESITO AYUDA POR FAVOR

Tags: html

ESTOY APRENDIENDO Y HICE ESTO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tu peso en un lugar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>tu peso en otro planeta</h1>
  <p>En la tierra pesas distinto que en jupiter y en marte</p>
  <scripttype=“text/javascript”>
    var usuario = prompt("Cual es tu peso");
    var planeta = parseInt(prompt("Elije tu planeta\n1 es marte, 2 es jupiter"));
    var peso = parseInt(usuario);
    var g_tierra = 9.8;
    var g_marte = 3.7;
    var g_jupiter = 24.8;
    var lugar;
    var peso_final;

    if (planeta == 1)
    {
     peso_final = peso * g_marte / g_tierra;
     lugar = "Marte";
    }
    else if (planeta == 2)
    {
     peso_final = peso * g_jupiter / g_tierra;
     lugar = "Jupiter";
     }
     else
     {
     peso_final = 100000;
     lugar = "kripton";
     }
    peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
    document.write("Tu peso en " + lugar + "es <strong>" + peso_final + " kilos</strong>");
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

LO QUIERO CARGAR EN EL NAVEGADOR DE CHROME Y ME SALE ASI[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu error esta aqui -> **<scripttype=“text/javascript”>** solo debes poner **<script>** es decir lo tienes mal escrito

Comment: por cierto no metas **spam** a tu pregunta no era necesario colocar tantas veces el mismo mensaje

Comment: O tambien `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: pero salvo que utilices algún meta lenguaje tal vez como typescript, veo irrelevante agregar **text/javascript** es decir se sobre entiende que si es una etiqueta script entonces leerá JS o no @alanfcm

Comment: Correcto, solo lo decia para que OP viera mejor cual fue su error.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!!

Comment: No es solo eso, también tiene un error en el formato de las comillas de inicio de "text/javascript", tal vez provenientes del html que copió y pegó, prueben copiar el html tal cual esta en la pregunta en un editor de texto y comprobarán lo que les digo.

Answer (score 0):

El unico problema que tenes es que copiaste mal esta parte, va separado y tenes que cambiar las comillas a estas " ".

```
 <scripttype=“text/javascript”>
```

Va asi:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

Con eso funciona perfecto:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Tu peso en un lugar</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>tu peso en otro planeta</h1>
   <p>En la tierra pesas distinto que en jupiter y en marte</p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var usuario = prompt("Cual es tu peso");
     var planeta = parseInt(prompt("Elije tu planeta\n1 es marte, 2 es jupiter"));
     var peso = parseInt(usuario);
     var g_tierra = 9.8;
     var g_marte = 3.7;
     var g_jupiter = 24.8;
     var lugar;
     var peso_final;

     if (planeta == 1)
     {
      peso_final = peso * g_marte / g_tierra;
      lugar = "Marte";
     }
     else if (planeta == 2)
     {
      peso_final = peso * g_jupiter / g_tierra;
      lugar = "Jupiter";
      }
      else
      {
      peso_final = 100000;
      lugar = "kripton";
      }
     peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
     document.write("Tu peso en " + lugar + "es <strong>" + peso_final + " kilos</strong>");
         </script>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: No es el único problema que tiene, si copias y  pegas el html que envió el usuario que hace la pregunta en tu editor de texto comprobarás que no funciona solo corrigiendo lo del espacio sino que además las comillas de inicio en "text/javascript" no son las comillas dobles convencionales sino que probablemente arrastran un error de formato de caracteres desde el html de donde copió y  pegó.

Comment: Lo acomode en el codigo que puse, si ejecutad el snippet vas a ver que funciona, salen los dos alert para completar y al finalizar devuelve el peso calculado, esta agregado en la respuesta eso q comentas

Answer (score 0):

si vas a la línea 9 de tu documento verás que se lee:

```
<scripttype=“text/javascript”>
```

Te falta un espacio entre script y type, así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

...y también debes cambiar las comillas de esa línea, parece que las copiaste y pegaste desde la web y te tomó un caracter que no son las comillas dobles normales, sino unas comillas medio extrañas, probé tu código en mi procesador de textos y noté ese error, quite esas comillas no standard y las sustituí por comillas dobles normales. Corrigiendo esas dos cosas el script funciona correctamente.